# Перевод междометия "WOW!"

Tags: заимствования

Позволительно ли переводить междометие "WOW!" на русский как "Вау!"? Не заменять же на русское "Ого!"... или возможна некая фонетическая версия  "У-у-а-а-у!"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все зависит от контекста, и вообще — от стиля повествования. Может, вам надо подчеркнуть гламурность героини, тогда "вау!" очень даже подойдет.

> > Не заменять же на русское "Ого!"

Почему же? Именно заменять. Можно и на "Ух ты!". А вот всякие фонетические версии "У-у-а-а-у!" читатель может принять за крик от боли или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: Да, нужно подчеркнуть гламурность, стиль просторечный. Вижу, ограничения на использование "Вау!" нет. Буду переводить как "Вау!".

Answer (score -2):

А как переводят это междометие французы, арабы, китайцы и все остальные уважающие себя культуры, Вы не знаете? У французов, например, "уау" запрещен законодательно. А как его переводили в СССР и России до 00-х годов? Только "ого", "ух ты", "ничего себе" и т.п. Если Вы хотите переводить на РУССКИЙ язык, то "уау" - это не перевод! Это подражание! Но, если Вы хотите переводить на гламурную феню, то можете и американский мат просто переписывать на кириллице.